# "No matching records found" remains after table population

Tags: javascript, datatables, angular-datatables

The "No matching records found" row remains on my table, even though data has been loaded.

[image: remaining text]

The table is defined as follows:

```
<table  datatable dt-options="gvc.dtOptions" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th data-priority="1">Alert Time</th>
    <th data-priority="2">Description</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="alert in gvc.recentAlerts">
    <td>{{alert.alert_time}}</td>
    <td>{{alert.sent_text}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And the dtOptions as follows in the controller:

```
    self.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withDOM('t')
  .withOption('scrollY', '200px')
  .withOption('scrollCollapse', true)
  .withOption('paging', false)
  .withOption('bSort', false)
  .withOption('responsive', true);
```

Any ideas as to why it is remaining?

Comment: Try setting `datatable="ng"` attribute for a `table`, see [angular way](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWay).

Comment: @Gyrocode.com is 100% right, it is easy to replicate the case.  Try to sort in one of the columns, all rows disappear because datatables not is aware of the data - it does not know angular has rendered the table.

Comment: Cheers @Gyrocode.com That has fixed the issue.

Comment: Have you tried datatable.draw() method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are you using Angular2 or higher, Component level SCSS or CSS (Not global level ),

```
::ng-deep table.dataTable td.dataTables_empty {
            display: none;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

As per instruction
put following code on src/styles.css (i.e. your global style)

```
  .dataTables_empty {
      display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For angular use this to remove "No matching records found" after data arrived from backend

```
      // Remove "No matching records found" 
      if (this.dtElement && this.sellers.length > 0) {
        this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
          // dtInstance.on('draw.dt', function () {
          if ($('.dataTables_empty').length > 0) {
            $('.dataTables_empty').remove();
          }
          // });
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with DataTables in handling API Response data from Services. Hence, try this simple solution:

Load your table only if you have data. I was having a **Resources** Array and I had put an ***ngIf** condition in Table HTML:

```
<table *ngIf="Resources !== undefined"  datatable class="table table-bordered">
 <thead>
  <tr></tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```